# How to write the code of this JFrame GUI (without drag and drop)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

how to implement the following jFrame using action Listener interface:

[image]

Sum of numbers button: find summation of all numbers you find in the statement, show result in message box

Last 5 chars button: show last 5 chars in the statement in message box

i can do it easily using drag and drop but the prof asked us to write the code and to make the layouts in the right place

Thank you!

Comment: If I was concerned more with getting done than weeding through documentation, although that's the best and inevitable thing that will happen if you stick with it, I would build it with the window builder and inspect the code it generated. That's called learning by example :)

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to read through either the [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) & [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) documentation or through the JavaFX documentation and then set everything up based on what you learn.

If you're up for it, you could also check out MigLayout which is a third-party layout manager. I find it a bit better for doing certain layouts compared to the default managers, but your proff probably wants you to use the defaults.